# Accessing methods on a class in a programmatic way without using if statements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, refactoring

I am refactoring and stumbled upon the samples below. I was wondering if I could condense this down as its mostly repeated code. As you can see the only real difference are the methods, executeTask, executeTaskFrom, acknowledgeTask, and killTask of the same class being conditionally called. My question is how you would refactor this and whether my solution or something like it is optimal.

This is what I have:

```
 taskGridOnCellclick(): void {
  if (datafield === "executeTask" && this.showButtons) {
      const taskName = this.taskGrid.getrowdata(this.editrow).taskName;

      // Call the service
      this.taskSvc.executeTask(this.dataForUi.processName, taskName).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.logger.debug(data);
        },
        error => {
          this.logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      );
    } else if (datafield === "executeAll" && this.showButtons) {
      const taskName = this.taskGrid.getrowdata(this.editrow).taskName;

      // Call the service
      this.taskSvc
        .executeTaskFrom(this.dataForUi.processName, taskName)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.logger.debug(data);
          },
          error => {
            this.logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
          }
        );
    } else if (datafield === "acknowledge" && this.showButtons) {
      const taskName = this.taskGrid.getrowdata(this.editrow).taskName;
      const taskStatus = this.taskGrid.getrowdata(this.editrow).taskStateName;

      if (
        taskStatus !== "Killed" &&
        taskStatus !== "Failed" &&
        this.showButtons
      ) {
      } else {
        //Call the service
        this.taskSvc
          .acknowledgeTask(this.dataForUi.processName, taskName)
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.logger.debug(data);
            },
            error => {
              this.logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
          );
      }
    } else if (datafield === "kill" && this.showButtons) {
      const taskName = this.taskGrid.getrowdata(this.editrow).taskName;
      const taskStatus = this.taskGrid.getrowdata(this.editrow).taskStateName;

      if (taskStatus !== "Running") {
      } else {
        //Call the service
        this.taskSvc.killTask(this.dataForUi.processName, taskName).subscribe(
          data => {
            this.logger.debug(data);
          },
          error => {
            this.logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

This is what I want:
Use:

```
taskProcessing(killTask())
```

Function:

```
  taskProcessing(fn:()=>{}){
  //Call the service
  this.taskSvc.fn(this.dataForUi.processName, taskName).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.logger.debug(data);
    },
    error => {
      this.logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  );
```

}

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner if you refactored each of those blocks into its own function.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's a good start but then wouldn't each of those functions pretty much be the same too?  I'd love it if I could somehow replace that one piece that differs as shown in my example.

Comment: Your first two `if` blocks look exactly the same.  Can you combine them using `if (datafield === "executeTask" || datafield === "executeAll)`?

Comment: They differ in that they call different methods from the same class... executeTask executeTaskFrom

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, frankly I don't think the code is all that bad.  All those continuations are necessary.  Each block is essentially a single function call with continuations.

Comment: Alright thanks for taking a look